The product of Petersson norm of Hecke eigenforms
Let $f_1,\dots,f_k$ be the normalized Hecke eigenforms in $S_{12k}(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$. Do we have asymptotic formula for the quantity $\prod_{i=1}^k \langle f_i,f_i \rangle_{\operatorname{Pet}}$ when $k \rightarrow \infty$? Here normalized means $a_1(f_i)=1$ and $\langle -,- \rangle_{\operatorname{Pet}}$ is the Petersson inner product.
I know $\langle f_i,f_i \rangle_{\operatorname{Pet}}$ is basically the adjoint $L$-value. So equivalently I ask for an asymptotic formula for $\prod_{i=1}^k L(\operatorname{Sym}^2(f_i),1)$.

I think it might be more realistic to asymptotically compute the geometric mean of the Petersson norms rather than the product.

Your best bet is to try to determine an asymptotic formula for $\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \log L(1,\operatorname{sym}^2 f_i)$ with a power-saving, via the Selberg trace formula.

To flesh out a little what Matt Young said, a more usual expression to study would be $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{I=1}^k L (\operatorname{Sym}^2(f_i),1)$. This expression should converge as $k$ goes to infinity to some computable constant $c$. If this converges to $c$ then the geometric mean converges to $e^c$ and the product has a formula $e^{ k (c +o(1))}$. Some people count such formulas as asymptotics in which case that would answer your question.

$c$ may be something like $\sum_{p} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}  \frac{ 1 + p^{-j} - p^{1-j}}{ j p^j}$.

For information, the first 30 values of the floor of the logarithm base 2 of the required product are [-20, -27, 4, 89, 237, 456, 752, 1132, 1598, 2157, 2811, 3563, 4418, 5376, 6443, 7618, 8904, 10305, 11821, 13454, 15209, 17082, 19082, 21200, 23450, 25823, 28325, 30958, 33723, 36616]

@WillSawin do you mean $\frac1k \sum_i \log L(\operatorname{Sym}^2(f_i),1)$? seems that you missed $\log$. How comes the conjectural limit $c=\sum_p \sum_j \frac{1+p^{-j}-p^{1-j}}{jp^j}$? All in all, could you possibly expand your comments as a answer so that I can accept it? (and learn more details.)

@QUBinggang Yes, I meant to put the log in there.
